# How to specify name for Symfony migration?

Tags: php, symfony

I trying to create new migration with Symfony:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:migrations:generate
Generated new migration class to "/path/to/project/app/DoctrineMigrations/Version20100621140655.php"
```

But I want create migration with name `Version20100621140655_MyName.php` instead of `Version20100621140655.php`. How can I do this?

**EDIT**

Linked theme: https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/issues/487

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the file and change the name of the class:

```
class Version20100621140655_MyName extends AbstractMigration
{ 

//
```

EDIT: doesn't seem to work, Doctrine is reporting a new migration but can't execute it...

Answer (score 7):

Since I came here by googling an none of the already posted answers gave me the direct solution, I figured it out by checking out GitHub issues and the Doctrine documentation.

I have tried the suggested answer from COil but my migrations failed at the post check, due to that the `versions` field in the `migration_versions` table is set to varchar(14) by default. Since the name will most probably become longer than that, you'd run into this error most of the time.

The solution is to adjust the `doctrine_migrations.yaml` file and add `column_length: YOUR_PREFERRED_LENGTH` (in my case 60).

```yaml
doctrine_migrations:
   ...
   column_length: 60
```

Now you can always manually rename your migration file and adjust the class name accordingly inside that file, to for example `Version20100621140655_MyName.php`.

```php
class Version20100621140655_MyName extends AbstractMigration
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this beyond creating your own command.

The class name is `Version<version>` as your can see in [the code](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Migrations/Tools/Console/Command/GenerateCommand.php#L510) and the file name, obviously, needs to be the same as that.

The version is created [here](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Migrations/Tools/Console/Command/DiffCommand.php#L111) using `$version = date('YmdHis')`.

For the benefit (a suffix to the file and class name) I doubt the work would be worth it to add this capability. You can always change the namespace easily enough though if you wanted to keep it in your app namespace using...

<kbd>app/config/config_dev.yml</kbd>

```
doctrine_migrations:
    ...
    namespace: Your\Migrations\Namespace
```